# Select2 multi-select items showing outside the input field, overlapping with other fields

Tags: css, django, forms, jquery-select2

I'm using Select2 multi-select in a Django app, and I'm having an issue where the selected items are being drawn outside the input field. Any thoughts on how the CSS has been mucked up to cause this?

Image showing multi-select items outside the field

[image: image showing multi-select items outside the field]

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Has it been a long time?
Try this

```
    .select2-selection--multiple {
    overflow: hidden !important;
    height: auto !important;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).